# Hide login and pass in a URL without POST

Tags: html, url, passwords

I have a url like 
https://USER:PASS@somesite.com/somefile.file

I want to hide or mask or whatever solution there is the password (at least). Why not POST? Because this link will be listed on the web, for the users to click it. The users don't need to be registered on the somesite.com, but I still want them to be able to download the file using some predefined credentials, I just don't want them to see it. I tried looking on the web for this specific problem but everybody suggests using a POST request.

I'm not HTML/web savy. I though on hashing the password but I think this is site specific.

Comment: is the format of your URL fixed or can you change it to solve this problem?

Comment: You can use some kind of random key based generator, which allows to download the content only for a specific set of users.

Comment: Given that it is a pure HTTP Authentication, this is unanswerable.

Comment: the other url is from a site i dont own, so i cant change it. the url is always the same, but it can point to different files

Answer (score 0):

First, you can put the Username and Password in the URL Parameters, like this:
https://somesite.com/somefile.file?username=USER&password=PASS

After doing that, you should encrypt them somehow, using some way that you choose,
so it might appear as:
https://somesite.com/somefile.file?username=4hD7&6&password=45jG5h

One small note:
It would be better to choose the parameter names to something less obvious than
`username` and `password`,
for example: `a` and `b`.
So the final result should look like:
https://somesite.com/somefile.file?a=4hD7&6&b=45jG5h

Comment: I can't do that since i do not own the website and it follows its pattern (which is was not able to figure out). In case you are wondering, this is the   website (its free to register) https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus